# Update button title with RSSelectionMenu library after popup selected cell

Tags: ios, swift

I found  that to update the text of my UIbutton with the value of the selected cell after popup with RSSectionMenu library seen [here](https://github.com/rushisangani/RSSelectionMenu), I could do the following:

```
selectionMenu.setSelectedItems(items: simpleSelectedArray) { (text, isSelected, selectedItems) in

    // update your existing array with updated selected items, so when menu presents second time updated items will be default selected.
    self.simpleSelectedArray = selectedItems
}
```

I tried doing this in my code but it does not work. When I print simpleSelectedArray it is empty. So please how can I collect the selected cell value and update my title button with. I am a beginner with Swift, Thanks!

HERE IS HOW I made USE OF THE POD Including the suggestion of given in the first comment.

```
 @IBAction func CategoryTapped(_ sender: Any) {

            let simpleDataArray = cat //I COLLECT cat for category and catID for category ID from my API

            let simpleDataArrayID = catId

            let selectionMenu =  RSSelectionMenu(dataSource: simpleDataArray) { (cell, object, indexPath) in
                cell.textLabel?.text = object
                cell.tintColor = .orange
            }
            selectionMenu.setSelectedItems(items: simpleSelectedArray) { (text, isSelected, selectedItems) in
        self.simpleSelectedArray.append(contentsOf: selectedItems)
        self.simpleSelectedArrayID.append(contentsOf: simpleDataArrayID)

for j in 0 ..< self.simpleSelectedArray.count {
         self.categoryupdate = self.simpleSelectedArray[j]

         self.EditCategory.setTitle(self.categoryupdate,for: .normal)

       self.categoryupdateID = self.simpleSelectedArrayID[j]

}
   self.updateAdcat(Category: self.categoryupdateID ) // Here I want to update my category by sending the ID of the selected category to the server. updateAdcat(id: Int) is my update function
            }

        selectionMenu.show(style: .Push, from: self)
        }
```

The problem now is I am unable to update the button title and collect the right corresponding ID. The selected title and the Id do not correspond.

Comment: What is "RSSectionMenu"? Can you give a more complete example? My first thought: the comment says, you have to update your existing array with the selected items, but you instead to replace your existing array. Not sure if it helps but you should call `self.simpleSelectedArray.removeAll()` and `self.simpleSelectedArray.append(contentsOf: selectedItems)`.This will keep the original reference of you existing array and only replace the content/items.

Comment: @UweMannl RSSectionMenu is a pod I installed, it can be found [here](https://github.com/rushisangani/RSSelectionMenu)

Comment: Okay, I see, the pod has the same code, so it should be fine ;) Could you post more of your code? Especially the part where you try to update the value of UIButton and where you print simpleSelectedArray.

Comment: @UweMannl I have moved a step further thanks to your first comment. With the above code, I can get the selected value, but now I want that once I selected, I should have the corresponding catID to use it in my updateAdcat function because my aim is to update the value of the category by using that button. Thank you!